# Animate rows within a ListView

Tags: android, listview, animation

I saw the Android app "Mobisle Notes Free" implement a really cool ListView, where a row gets moved to the bottom if its checkbox is checked. It's not just a simple refresh, but an actual animation where you see the row travel to the bottom. Does anyone know how to implement this?

Comment: Follow the link http://stackoverflow.com/q/3928193/1054930 which defines the listview animation beautifully

Comment: You can refer the following link:

http://stackoverflow.com/q/3928193/1054930

Answer (score 0):

You could check out the Android example application “ApiDemos.”  It provides you with some source code that can show you how to do widget based animation.

Edit:

I believe it is classes Animation1, Animation2, and Animation3.

Comment: Do you know which example that would be? Saw something around ListViews, but couldn't find the one where the list items animate up and down the list

Comment: Couldn't find those. The only animations I could see in the API are those that move or resize an object, but not the moving or rearranging of ListView items.