# Replace row of a listview with animation Android

Tags: android, listview, animation

Could you please suggest me ideas about how to animate the replacing of a row of a listview with animation after a 'long item click'. I'd like to do something like Twitter's app, when you 'long click' on a tweet.
Thank you.

Comment: reaplace meaning delete?

Comment: No, change a list view item dynamically

Comment: http://graphics-geek.blogspot.in/ animation of listview. The blogger is a android developer @ google. Video + codes.

Comment: Are you sure about your link?

Comment: yes. i posted the wrong one and now edited now. check it

Comment: OK, I've subscribed months ago to Android Developers' youtube channel and regularly watch these videos. There's nothing about changing list view item :/

Comment: Changing meaning either you add new data or delete the data from listview row. So what do you mean by changing?. Ignore if the links don't help.

Comment: I mean exactly what the twitter app does when you 'long click' on a row.

Answer (score 1):

First, your should get the item you want:

```
int visiblePosition = yourListView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
View v = yourListView.getChildAt(itemIndex - visiblePosition);
```

Second, start an animation on the item:

```
Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
                 GoTransitApp.this, android.R.anim.slide_out_right
             );
anim.setDuration(500);
v.startAnimation(anim );
```

Hope this will help you!

Reference:
[Android – Update single item in ListView](http://erikw.eu/android-update-single-item-in-listview/)

[animation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6857762/1755542)

Comment: Thanks, but what about the layout which is aimed to replace the current one in the row as I explained? I wanna do what a 'long click' does on a tweet in Twitter app.

Comment: Do you mean a new layout on turn up like twitter? You can just put the   layout on top the existing layout and make it visibility=gone, then make it visibility=visible when long pressed happend

Comment: AlphaAnimation alphaAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(0.2f, 1.0f);  start this animation on your new layout.