# Step for step tutorial for setting simple animation when deleting/inserting rows in listview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-animation

I want to change the animation when inserting or deleting rows in listview to something simple and very easy to see what happened (insert/deletion).

I would like to see an easy and basic tutorial on how to do this. I could always change the animation afterwards, but first i just need to learn how to attach animation to listview and trigger it when deleting/inserting rows.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Refer to the following link for more informations: 

[ListView Animations][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3928193/how-to-animate-addition-or-removal-of-android-listview-rows

Answer (score -1):

http://karnshah8890.blogspot.com/2013/04/listview-animation-tutorial.html

That gives a pretty good way to do it. All you have to include is logic that only fires the animations when an item is added or deleted. That shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but you did not answer my question. Like I said, defining the animation is not my concern for the moment. What I wonder is how to attach the animation to the delete and insert actions. And that is not explained in the article you are referencing.